# Log fields/variables to file in web application

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I have log4j2 configured in my web app which logs debug/info messages to console. I want to use a logger to write specific fields which are received in each http request to a new file. I understand that adding a file appender to existing `log4j2.xml` file would write all the log messages where logging is configured, but I want to use this new logger only to write specific fields.

I guess a rollingfile appender will help, which creates a new file for every request and save some input fields received as part of that request.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you point out what exactly is still troubling you? Making a separate logger or which appender to use? Or ... what? I am a bit confused by the question, sorry.

Comment: I have tried adding a rolling file appender but it adds all the log messages to file. I am unable to figure out how to configure this appender to only create a file with fields which I want to log intead of writing all the debug/info etc logs to this file. I am probably need to have two logger instances, one generic and one specific. Hope this makes it clear

Comment: Ah, ok. Yes you need to create another logger instance. For example with `Logger fieldLogger = LogManager.getLogger("FIELDLOG");` Then you can reference that logger in your configuration and add separate appenders to it.

Comment: Yes.. That is what I intend to do. Any idea on how to configure the xml to roll a new file  for each incoming requests which is a rest call to a controller. Thanks

Comment: @Fildor I would accept your previous comment if you can post it as an answer. As that serves most of what I was looking for i.e. to have multiple logger instances in same file.

Answer (score 0):

You have full control on what you log.
Use the logger to specifically log all the fields you need. 
All the fields you do not specifically log, are not logged.

For example the following line will log only SelectedField1 and SelectedFieldN. 
All other fields in the application will not be logged.

```
logger.debug("SelectedField1:"+selectedField1+"SelectedFieldN:"+selectedFieldN);
```

Comment: Now suppose if the same class has another log statement say, logger.debug("Entered process method.. This is FYI.. "); I wan't to skip such messages from being added to file.

Comment: You can create a special logger for your http request. And use a dedicated file for it.

Comment: Yes @Spyros That is what I am looking for on how to create the rolling strategy so that a new file can be created on every entry to controller method. Also mentioned in question comment as well. Thanks

Comment: If you need that you can create a dedicated logger with a dedicated file.
Each time you log, you should recreate the logger. Use append=false, and unlimited files.